# Puppeteer how to click the child element of 'next sibling'

Tags: css-selectors, puppeteer

I want to select and click the specified `<a>` of next sibling, html code
below:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a></a>
  </li>
  <li class='abc'>
    <a></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a></a> <!-- I want to click this link -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

the `<ul>` is changing, but the `<li class='abc'>` is changeless

and use the code below:

```
    let tag = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelector('li.abc').nextSibling.a
    })

    console.log(tag?'Y': 'N')
    // await page.click(tag)
```

then it output 'N'

Can someone help me fix this error？
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now it solved use `page.click('.abc + li > a');` Thanks Dave Batiste(user of puppeteer.slack.com)

Comment: Why not post ot as the answer?

Comment: Hi @marslord, can you please help me with the below issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69648540/how-to-navigate-to-following-sibling-in-puppeteer

Answer (score 4):

Got this answer from Dave Batiste（user of puppeteer.slack.com),

Thanks to @Vaviloff point that: I should post this answer.

Use the code `page.click('.abc + li > a')` can click the specified `<a>` that I want to,
and Dave Batiste(user of puppeteer.slack.com) give more info as below:

> If you do want a handle that you can call methods on, I think you'd be interested in > `page.$`...
>
> ```
> const handle = await page.$(selector);
> handle.click(options);
> ```