# How to navigate to following sibling in puppeteer

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

Here I wanted to navigate to the h6 tag, from first div, so can anyone help me with the xpath or css using following sibling concept?

```
<div class="MuiCardHeader-root"></div>
<div class="MuiCardContent-root jss63568">
<h6 class="MuiTypography-root jss63569 null MuiTypography-subtitle2">Card-954-description</h6></div>
```

Comment: Try `'div.MuiCardHeader-root ~ h6'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is syntax for selector in CSS for next element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660046/what-is-syntax-for-selector-in-css-for-next-element)